# Unable to attach image to in-app SMS

Tags: ios, image, switch-statement, sms, attachment

I have a simple app that takes partial screenshot and then SMS the resultant image.

The image attached to the SMS in the pop-up SMS dialogue window is not the image I captured via screenshot - it's a 'blank' image.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func smsScreenShot(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Declare the snapshot boundaries

    let top: CGFloat = 100
    let bottom: CGFloat = 60

    // The size of the cropped image
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - top - bottom)

    // Start the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    // use context in a couple of places
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Transform the context so that anything drawn into it is displaced "top" pixels up
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -top)

    // Draw the view into the context (this is the snapshot)
    view.layer.renderInContext(context)

    let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context (this is required to not leak resources)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    // Composing the SMS
    if !MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        print("SMS services are not available")
    }

    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {

        let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

        composeVC.recipients = []
        composeVC.body = "Have a look at this image!!";

        // Attaching the image to the SMS.
        let image = snapshot
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename:"my image")
        self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I have researched this for hours and don't see where I am going wrong.

I have the identical code for adding the attachment to an in-app email, with obvious differences in the controllers, and it works fine. Just not working with regards to in-app SMS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:-

```
composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename:"my image")
```

to this:-

```
 composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename:"myimage.png")
```

There you go!

Comment: Awesome! It works! Any idea why `composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename:"my image")` worked for my in-app email and not in-app sms?

Comment: You were specifying wrong " UTI (Uniform Type Identifier)" , just check https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009257

Comment: Excellent! Terima Kasih :)

Comment: Saya berbesar hati ;)

Comment: Hahaha! Bravo my friend!